# Deezer API Redirect does Not Work on Localhost

Tags: api, oauth, localhost, redirect, deezer

I am trying to set up an `OAUTH` flow with python to connect to the Deezer API. I am using flask as my local server.

However when I try to connect as a user, I get the message You must enter a valid redirect URI and I am not redirected back to my localhost site. I have tried the following in the Deezer app settings, but nothing works!

Application Domain: 127.0.0.1:5000;
Redirect URL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/deez_authorized

Application Domain: localhost:5000;
Redirect URL: http://localhost:5000/deez_authorized

Application Domain: localhost;
Redirect URL: http://localhost:5000/deez_authorized

I have searched all related questions on stack overflow, but none have answered the issue. Surely you must be able to use localhost for development purposes no?

Comment: I have an [example of a simple Flask app](https://github.com/Teoretic6/deezer-api-example) on Github, which works with Deezer API and works in localhost also - you can check it out. I also wrote a big instruction there of how to setup it, so maybe with its help you will be able to detect the problems in your setup. Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am having the same issue and I get this message in the browser console: "Refused to display <url>  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'".